# Center a symbol on a bent arrow: tikzcd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

The following code

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
x \ar[loop,out=150,in=210,distance=20,swap,"g_1\circ f"] \ar[r,"f"] & y \ar[l,bend right=70,swap,"g_1"] \ar[l,bend left=70,"g_2"]
\ar[loop,out=30,in=-30,distance=20,"f\circ g_2"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
```

generate
[image]

My problem is that g_2 (below the bent arrow from y to x) is not center in the same vertical along with g_1 and f. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried specifying `pos=0.5`, `midway`, and even `pos=0.499`, but all to no avail. I'm not sure of the actual problem (perhaps the glyph height of `g_2`?), but `pos=0.49` is one ugly fix:

(Also remember to make all MWEs compilable.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
x \ar[loop,out=150,in=210,distance=20,swap,"g_1\circ f"] \ar[r,"f"] & y \ar[l,bend right=70,swap,"g_1"] \ar[l,bend left=70,pos=0.49,"g_2"]
\ar[loop,out=30,in=-30,distance=20,"f\circ g_2"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]